# How to change background color of the chart?

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

Use this c3js and d3js libraries and I want to change the background color of the complete chart.
My example seems not to work.

c3js (v. c3-0.6.7)

d3js (v. d3-5.7.0)

```
<style type="text/css">
 #mychart { background-color: gray; }
</style>

   [...] 

<div id="mychart" ></div>

   [...] 

<script type="text/javascript">
   [...] 
   var chart = c3.generate({
       bindto: '#mychart',
   [...] 
</script>
```

Comment: if you use `#mychart svg { background-color: gray; }`

Comment: @rioV8 Yes, this works!